# javascript reduce function not working in IE11

Tags: javascript

I have a rather big array in javascript and use function below to pick out values and sum them, works fine in Chrome but nog in IE

```
var test = checkoutConfig.quoteItemData.reduce((a, v) => a += parseFloat(v.row_weight),0);
```

There are other questions about this issue, but i can't figure it out...

Comment: It is the arrow syntax `=>` that doesn't work in IE

Comment: you are mistaken sir, reduce works perfectly well in IE11

Comment: Nope, really nog working in IE 11. Maybe the reduce does, but the total function doesnt

Comment: @LGSon, that is what i found indeed. But what is the sollotion to that?

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar Check the dupe link (or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))...it uses/shows `function(){...}` instead

Comment: var sum = checkoutConfig.quoteItemData.reduce(function (a,v) {
  return a += parseFloat(v.row_weight);
}, 0);